# Acceder a una informacion de una tabla que no tiene propiedades de navegacion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

### No se me ocurre como poder acceder a una tabla sin propiedades de  navegacion

Resulta que tengo una relacion similar a la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la que gracias a las **propiedades de navegacion**  puedo acceder a los `procedimientos` de un paciente consultando la tabla `paciente` de la siguiente forma:

```
var Paciente = await db.Paciente
                    .Include(f => f.idProcedimientosNavigation)
                    .Join(db.Cirugias,
                          PacCir => PacCir.paciente_id,        
                          Paciente => Paciente.IdPaciente, 
                          (PacClinico, Paciente) => new { PacCir = PacCir})
                    .Where(f => f.idPaciente== id)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

> La duda es realmente es como puedo acceder a la informacion de `cirugias` consultando la tabla `Paciente`, ya que la tabla `Paciente` no tiene propiedades de navegacion

**Lo que he intentado:**

Anteriormente cuando se han presentado este tipo de sitaciones han sido consultas mas extensas en las que tuve que crear un `dto`, pero para esta consulta tan simple no creo que valga la pena, por eso quisiera saber que otra opcion podria resultar, he intentado usar `joins` tambien, sin exito alguno

### Edit: en otras ocasiones uso un dto y linq, mostrare como lo haria para este caso

```
//En el dto
public Class PacienteClinicoDto{
   public Class Paciente PacienteC {get;set;}
   public List<Cirugia> CirugiaC {get;set;}
}
// y en la consulta//
var Paciente = await db.Paciente
                      .Include(f => f.idProcedimientosNavigation)
                      .Where(f => f.idPaciente== id)
                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

if(Paciente){
  PacienteClinico = new PacienteClinicoDto
  {
     //Aca tendria el paciente y los procedimientos
     PacienteC = Paciente;
     //Aca obtendria las cirugias del paciente.
     CirugiasC = db.Cirugias
                 .Where(f=>f.paciente_id==Paciente.idPaciente)
                 ToListAsync();
  }
}
```

**Mi duda es si hay alguna otra opcion de hacerlo sin hacer uso de un dto, o si esta es la mejor opcion de hacerlo**

Comment: "sin éxito alguno" `<--` ¿cómo lo intentaste?

Comment: usando la sintaxis [de esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/join-where-with-linq-and-lambda),  esta sintaxis la use para otros casos en donde finalmente opte por construir un dto.

Comment: Y por qué no incluiste la sintaxis de esa respuesta en tu pregunta. La respuesta a la que haces referencia es correcta y sería exactamente lo que muchos harían. Puedes pegar el código donde lo intentaste "sin éxito alguno"?

Comment: @Arriel editado agregando el `join`

Comment: Veo que insistes en utilizar la sintaxis lambda. Ya intentaste LinqToSql?

Comment: No entiendo del todo tu pregunta. Cuál es la entrada?? desde que campo/elemento partes buscando ?? y Luego cuál es tu salida esperada?

Comment: Aclarando mis preguntas anteriores. El caso obvio que se me viente a la mente es tener las cirujias de un paciente, pero para eso no necesitas un join, vas y preguntas por las cirugías de paciente_id

Comment: @Arriel he usado linqToSql pero creando un dto, esa es la razon de mi pregunta **Hay alguna forma de usar linq sin crear un dto?**, quiero evitar crear un dto para solamente hacer un join

Comment: @Yussef asi es, la entrada es un `id` con el cual consulto la tabla paciente y quiesiera tener las cirugias de un paciente sin tener que hacer otra consulta, algo similar a un inner join. Lo he hecho pero para eso he tenido que crear un dto, **Voy a editar la pregunta para mostrar como lo he hecho antes**, para ver si hay otras opciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los primero es aclarar que cuando tienes las propiedades de navegación bien configuradas no necesitas hacer un `join` entre las entidades relacionadas.

Y al contrario, cuando no tienes estas propiedades de navegación es que te puedes valer del `join` para lograr una relación "lógica".

Por otro lado el uso de una clase adicional que tu llamas "DTO" (pero que en rigor no es un DTO) es irrelevante para la consulta misma, solo tiene importancia en registrar la salida de la consulta. Por lo que tú dices, concluyo que tu problema principal es que no quieres crear una clase adicional, para esto puedes usar un a Clase anónima, es decir haces `new { prop1 = algo, prop2 = otracosa }`.

Ejemplo

```
var Paciente =(from p in db.Paciente
              where p.f.idPaciente== id
              select new
              {
                 Paciente = p,
                 Cirujias = db.Cirugias.Where(c => f.idPaciente==c.paciente_id)
              }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Con un join también puede ser, en este caso debería ser un `left join`

```
var Paciente =(from p in db.Paciente
               from c in db.Cirugias.Where(c => f.idPaciente==c.paciente_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
              where p.f.idPaciente== id
              select new
              {
                 Paciente = p,
                 Cirujias = c
              }).FirstOrDefault();
```

*Nota: La palabra reservada de Linq `join` hace mención a un `inner join`, para un `left join` se usa `DefaultIfEmpty()` de la manera representada en el código anterior*